# MongoDB with C# Driver: How to filter on field within nested array of objects

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm new to MongoDB and have been struggling with this a bit. Let's say I have a document with an id, name, and array of objects:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "614ba49b46727413d60b99e2"
    },
    "Name": 1,
    "ObjectArray": [
    {
        "ObjectId": {
            "$oid": "614ba49b46727413d60b99e3"
        },
        "Value": "some value", 
    }, 
    {
        "ObjectId": {
            "$oid": "614ba49b46727413d60b99e5"
        },
        "Value": "other value",
    }
    ],
}
```

I have a C# class that maps to this document and everything works in that regard.  Let's say I want to add another object to the object array only if the new object's Id doesn't already exist in the array?  I'm using C# Driver for this and have tried several things.

I've tried several ideas including the following --

```cs
var filter = FilterBuilder.Eq(x => x.Id, id) & 
             FilterBuilder.Nin(x => x.ObjectArray[-1].ObjectId, new[] { newDoc.ObjectId});
```

This unfortunately only checks the first object in the object array.  So as asked before how do I only add a new object to an array if a condition exists all within one filter?

Thanks for your time.

*** Solution ***

Used Elematch in conjunction with Not to do the filtering all in one.

```cs
var filter = FilterBuilder.Eq(x => x.Id, id) & 
            FilterBuilder.Not(FilterBuilder.ElemMatch(x => x.ObjectArray, 
                 Builders<ObjectClass>.Filter.Eq(y => y.ObjectId, newDoc.ObjectId)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to access and filter nested property. And compare the value with `$eq`.

```
{
  "ObjectArray": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "ObjectId": {
        $eq: <value>
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> Complete MongoDB aggregation query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          "_id": {
            // With Exist _id
            $eq: ObjectId("614ba49b46727413d60b99e2")
          }
        },
        {
          "ObjectArray": {
            $elemMatch: {
              "ObjectId": {
                // With unexist ObjectArray.ObjectId
                $eq: ObjectId("614ba49b46727413d60b99e3")
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A_IcxGMSZTB)

> For MongoDB .NET/C# driver

```cs
var filter = FilterBuilder.Eq(x => x.Id, id) & 
             FilterBuilder.ElemMatch(x => x.ObjectArray, 
                 Builders<ObjectClass>.Filter.Eq(y => y.ObjectId, newDoc.ObjectId);
```

Replace `ObjectClass` with the class name for the Object in `ObjectArray`.

**Remarks**:

With the above solution, it will return the document when the parsed `ObjectId` is existed in `ObjectArray`. Hence you should **do the handling** for the **existed `ObjectId` case**.

And **add the document to `ObjectArray`** only when **no document is queried**.

---

### References

1. [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)
2. [Similar scenario for filtering a document in an array with MongoDB .NET/C# driver](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-write-this-aggregate-query-in-c/6940/2)

Comment: Finally got it working with elematch for the c# driver.  Had to use the Not function in conjunction with elematch.  Thanks for your answer.